# GORM: How to alias a relation in a JOIN?

Tags: go, go-gorm

If I have a query like this where a join on a relation:

```
db.Model(&User{}).Joins("UserProfile").Find(&result)
```

I get sql like:

```
SELECT * FROM sf_guard_user LEFT JOIN sf_guard_user_profile UserProfile ON sf_guard_user.id = UserProfile.user_id
```

How can I get the join to use a different alias (here I want `user_profile`)?

The models for reference (simplified):

```
type User struct {
    ID                uint32         `gorm:"type:int(11);primaryKey;autoIncrement"`
    Username          *string        `gorm:"type:varchar(128);default:null;unique;uniqueIndex"`
    IsActive          bool           `gorm:"type:tinyint(4);not null;default:1"`
    IsFirstSignin     *bool          `gorm:"type:tinyint(1);default:1"`
    UserProfile       *UserProfile   `gorm:"foreignKey:UserId;references:id"`
}

func (User) TableName() string {
    return "sf_guard_user"
}
```

```
type UserProfile struct {
    UserId                    uint32         `gorm:"type:int(11);not null;unique;uniqueIndex"`
    User                      *User          `sieve:"skip"`
    FirstName                 *string        `gorm:"type:varchar(32);default:null;index" sieve:"join:user_profile"`
    LastName                  *string        `gorm:"type:varchar(32);default:null;index"`
}

func (UserProfile) TableName() string {
    return "sf_guard_user_profile"
}
```